# Swing app installation

Tags: java, mysql, swing, deployment

I've made Java Swing application using hibernate (it automatically creates tables etc. when it is run). I need to make some installation version to my application, is it enough to just upload my jar file? What should I do when I want to publish my application? Just prepare link to jar and some readme which contains info that for example:

1. install newest version of java ( http://www.java.com/download )
2. make msyql database user 'user' with password 'password'
3. create database "application".
4. run application.jar

### Edit

I want to simulate process of selling my application to some company. For example my application is hmm to manage some store, u can put there some notes, bills etc. This application works on some database, which ll be placed somewhere in this store, I don't want to make this application accessible from internet. So how should i install it? Readme file example was kinda bad, now we can assume that i need to go there and install for them database and configure it. So at the moment I need only to make possibility for company to install my software without me help, in cases for example hiring 100 new people.

Comment: If I was told to install mysql database, configure one just to run some software, I'd find dev and shoot him/her in head. Now seriously, it's up to you, how you will publish your app. It's out of programming scope.

Comment: Depends in which context, i'd prefer using Java Web Start cause there you can update your app

Comment: this is a dealbreaker = 2 make msyql database user 'user' with password 'password'

Comment: Is your application intended to run on multiple clients accessing one centralized database instance? Or is there only one database per application?

Comment: one database for many clients

Comment: you still want to use java web start, doesn't have to be in "internet" could be only `localhost`

Answer (score 2):

If you want your app been redistributable. I'd use Java web start. Read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/)

Java Web Start software provides Java developers and users with many deployment advantages:

> With Java Web Start software, you can place a single Java application
>   on a web server for deployment to a wide variety of platforms,
>   including Windows, Linux, and Solaris. Java Web Start software
>   supports multiple, simultaneous versions of the Java platform. An
>   application can request a specific version of the Java Runtime
>   Environment (JRE) software without conflicting with the needs of other
>   applications. Users can create a desktop shortcut to launch a Java Web
>   Start application outside a browser. Java Web Start software takes
>   advantage of the inherent security of the Java platform. By default,
>   applications have restricted access to local disk and network
>   resources. Applications launched with Java Web Start software are
>   cached locally for improved performance. Updates to a Java Web Start
>   application are automatically downloaded when the application is run
>   standalone from the user's desktop.

See also stackoverflow's info page [Java web start info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the fine answer of @nachokk, I'll expand on points 1-3.

1. The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).
2. (& 3.)  Look to using the `ExtensionInstallerService`.  That is what you'd used to install/configure the DB itself.  Here is a [demo. of the service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an installer with [IzPack](http://izpack.org/).
It can also be combined with [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to download the JRE.